# Fetching JSON from URL with Ruby, throwing TypeError and 'Failed to open TCP connection'

Tags: json, ruby, terminal

**Background**

I have a Ruby terminal app that generates a URL, and then fetches JSON from that URL.

Manually following the link (https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Harry+Potter) shows a JSON object, but the program throws two errors.

1. (no implicit conversion of Array into String) (TypeError)
2. Failed to open TCP connection to [{"kind"=>"books#volume", "id"=>"2sSMCwAAQBAJ", "etag"=>"vAZ9LJGLnng", "selfLink"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/2sSMCwAAQBAJ", "volumeInfo"=>{"title"=>"Harry Potter and the Cursed Child – Parts One and Two (Special Rehearsal Edition)", "authors"=>["J.K. Rowling", "John Tiffany", "Jack Thorne"]...(very long)

I'm confused as it says it cannot open a connection, but the data is there, although it's in a different format.

**My Code**

The relevant code is as follows.

```
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(link,"")
    puts response.body -- error is thrown on line above, so this is commented out
```

Note: 'link' in this case is the first link I gave.

**Question**

How can I correct the errors given, so that my application gets a JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get response try this:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Harry+Potter'

# get JSON as String
json = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))

# get Hash from JSON
hash = JSON.parse(json)
```

The problem was of URI parsing.

You can also do it as:

```
Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body
```

Comment: I think that's done it. Was it just an issue of not parsing the result?

Comment: Yes. Parsing was problem. I added information to the answer. If it helps you, you can check it.